# Unable to run elasticsearch with weblogic server

Tags: elasticsearch, weblogic12c

I am using elasticsearch 7.2.0 with weblogic 12.2.1.3 server. Facing classloading issues.

I have setup weblogic server 12.2.1.3 and elastic search 7.2.0. Facing runtime error when searching.

All the elasticsearch jars are included in the domain/lib directory.

Comment: Can you post errors and stack trace showing the issue please.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.. there was a conflict with old and new versions of lucene-core jars used by elasticsearch. Both were present in the library. After removing the old version, elasticsearch works fine